# PHP-FPM Can't connect to Mysql via localhost but can by ip

Tags: mariadb, php

Using mariadb 10.2, php 7.0, in Centos 6.9 hosted cpanel server.  Everything is installed and compiled through cpanel.

If I put PHP into FPM mode it cannot connect to DB unless I specify 127.0.0.1

If I switch PHP to CLI / DSO etc, it connects to localhost just fine.

I've done PHP info and verified that PHP does see the correct .sock file, and it is consistent when PHP is in CLI / DSO.

Is this a mysql problem, or a PHP-FPM problem?

my.cnf:

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password       = your_password
port=3306
socket="/tmp/mysql.sock"

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
performance_schema=0
#innodb_force_recovery = 1
port=3306
socket="/tmp/mysql.sock"
key_buffer_size=64M
max_allowed_packet=268435456
bulk_insert_buffer_size=64M
table_open_cache=32768
open_files_limit=65536
sort_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=2M
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=128M
myisam_max_sort_file_size=10G
thread_cache_size=8
myisam-recover-options = DEFAULT
query_cache_size=256M
query_cache_limit=2M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
#thread_concurrency=16
max_connections=100
#max_user_connections = 40
max_delayed_threads=0
log-error="/var/log/mysql.error.log"
log-warnings
ft_min_word_len=3
wait_timeout=300
tmp_table_size=512M
max_heap_table_size=512M
table_definition_cache=12000
join_buffer_size=256K

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
#log-bin
# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id=1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin

# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir          = /var/db/mysql-tmp
#log-update     = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 64M
#bdb_max_lock = 100000

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_data_home_dir="/var/lib/mysql/"
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir="/var/lib/mysql/"
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=10M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size=128M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_log_files_in_group=3
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_read_io_threads=4
innodb_write_io_threads=4
#innodb_thread_concurrency=4
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=90
#innodb_use_native_aio = 0

# Added to make innodb file less scary (KL 5/20/08)
innodb_file_per_table=1

default-storage-engine=InnoDB
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=32M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer=128M
sort_buffer_size=128M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M
[myisamchk]
key_buffer=128M
sort_buffer_size=128M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld_safe]
open-files-limit=8192
```

Comment: You do understand that you need different GRANTs for localhost vs IP?  What error did you get?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Comment: What were you doing at the time?  Any idea what file it was reaching for?

Comment: Just sitting idle. This server is not in production yet. I assumed it was reaching for the sock file?

Comment: I made several tests and attempts. It seems that FPM is the source of the problem. It's just not resolving `localhost` to an IP.